# Different keyboard layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I just took a look on different devices and their soft keyboards. They are all looking a bit different. I attach two screenshots. One is from my HTC Desire (Android 2.2), another one from Emulator (Android 2.3). 
As you can see on the device the enter key is on device just a symbol, on emulator it is "send".

Can I change it somehow?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem a year ago, my problem was that the numeric keypad is very different from each provider (not only on style but on the buttons that are shown)

In my personal experience is a pain to try to change that, you would need to create your own SoftKeyboard class with your own images.

If it's not an important issue I recommend to just pass over it, or find a keyboard type that satisfies your needs.

However, I don't know if in the newest versions of Android you get an easier way to customize keyboards.

Good luck on there :)